# Transfer SQL Server Objects Task Error: Execution failed with the following error: "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am using  Transfer SQL Server Objects Task in SSIS to create a package for copying procedures from prod to dev.

> [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task] Error: Execution failed with the following error: "Invalid column name XYZ"

Any help on the above error will be appreciated.

Raghu

*SQL Server Objects Task properties Screenshots*

[image: Transfer SQL Server Objects Task properties]

[image: Transfer SQL Server Objects Task properties1]

[image: Transfer SQL Server Objects Task properties2]

Comment: add sample code procedure and screenshot of package

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Transfer SQL SServer Objects Task properties?

Comment: Hi Hadi, I have added Transfer SQL SServer Objects Task properties screenshots

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because you are trying to copy a stored procedure that is using the column `XYZ` from a Table, and this table is not copied or not found in the destination database.

Also From the screenshots, you are not copying Tables from the Source Database. *('CopyAllTables` property is False)* , So make sure you choose all related tables to the stored procedure to be copied to the destination database